# Rebrand Oracle Weblogic Console 12.2.1.x.x

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I had a task to rebrand the weblogic console accessed at

```
http://localhost:7001/console/login/LoginForm.jsp.
```

I need to edit LoginForm.jsp, but I notice for Oracle weblogic
version 12.2.x.x.x `LoginForm.jsp` is not present in the directory,
but theres a [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24966/rebrand.htm#CNSLX145) for 12.1.x.x.x where the LoginForm.jsp is present.

Answer (score 0):

I routed to login on a different directory instead of figuring out how oracle generates the LoginForm.jsp.

Go to web.xml
{WL_HOME}/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT,FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login2/LoginForm.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login/LoginError.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
```

Edited value for tag **form-login-page**

Then create the directory

```
{WL_HOME}/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/webapp/login2/LoginForm.jsp
```

I just inspect the element thru my browser to copy the contents of LoginForm.jsp